# Monitor has a stuck flickering image on the background, it persists through reboots, and it persists through different GPUs

Tags: graphics-card, display, gpu, graphics, repair

This is very odd behavior I have never seen because it seems the monitor itself, has RAM that has burned in or capacitors keep a buffer up or something for hours, because I have removed all power and tried several reboots and resets and an image of a program since the first time it crashed is still there at the background flickering while you can hover other programs on it but they still get distorted as well.

I would normally consider this a falty panel, but it is clearly a hardware issue in the rest of the monitor itself, because the OSD comes up crystal clear with the artifacted image flickering behind it and windows has the fault after several reboots and on different GPU slots (I have 3 monitors and 2 GPUs).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the issue well. Could you add a photo of the screen?

Comment: Many modern displays do have *some* form of buffering and image processing, so it is entirely possible for those buffers capturing incoming data go bad and end up with odd scanline like effects.